# Can't find cause to : syntax error, unexpected '>' in ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, carousel

Ok, this might be stupid, but I've spent the whole night trying to find the cause to this error in my code without luck.

My last option is to see if your eyes sees better than mine.

I'm getting this error in the line below (line 68):

```
   <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "<%= index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : '' %>" %>
```

The full snippet is below:

```
 <div class='carousel-inner '>
            <% @product.images.each_with_index do |image_product, index| %>
                <div class=<%= index == 0 ? 'item active' : '' %> >
                    <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "<%= index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : '' %>" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <script>
              $("#zoom_05").elevateZoom({ zoomType    : "inner", cursor: "crosshair" });
            </script>
        </div>
        <!-- sag sol -->
        <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
        </a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And full errror messages:

```
 syntax error, unexpected '>'
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:74: unknown regexp options - crpt
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:75: syntax error, unexpected '<'
            </div>
             ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:78: unknown regexp options - pa
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:79: syntax error, unexpected '<'
            </a>
             ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:81: unknown regexp options - pa
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:82: syntax error, unexpected '<'
            </a>
             ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:83: unknown regexp options - dv
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:84: syntax error, unexpected '<'
                    <!-- thumb -->
                     ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:84: syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
                    <!-- thumb -->
                                ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:86: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_LAMBDA
...oduct.images.each_with_index do |image_product, index| 
...                               ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:86: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '='
...index do |image_product, index| 
...                               ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:90: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'.freeze;             end 
                         ^
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:135: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/hlinreykdal/app/views/products/show.html.erb:137: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `<% %>`, you need to use string interpolation instead, like this:

```
<%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "#{index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : ''}" %>
```

Although, since you are already in ruby code, you don't need any kind of interpolation at all, so you can just do:

```
<%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: index == 0 ? "zoom_05" : "" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess is that this:

```
<%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "<%= index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : '' %>" %>
```

Should be this:

```
<%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "#{index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : ''}" %>
```

Specifically, swapping:

```
<%= index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : '' %>
```

for:

```
#{index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : ''}
```

Your issue is likely that you're already in a `<%= %>` line, so you can't do `<%= %>` again inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `<%=` to needlessly perform string interpolation.

`<%=` tags are part of ERB, and you can't nest them. Inside a `<% %>`, you're not in an ERB context anymore, you're writing plain Ruby. If you were going to perform string interpolation, you would use `"#{ ... }"`. However, there is no need for string interpolation at all here.

Your line should read:

```
<%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: (index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : '') %>
```